# app icons on Xcode5 are always blank - what is wrong?

Tags: xcode5

I followed all the steps to migrate the app icons to xcode5. All Icons appear correctly in the Images.xcassets folder and on the screen where I dragged them. They all have correct sizes. The target's app icon shows the correct set where all the icons are.

But when I start the app in the simulator the icon is always blank. No matter what device and iOS version I choose.

I reset the simulator many times, rebooted, restarted xcode, cleaned the project, deleted derived data - nothing helps.

ANy idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend not transferring the images, rather switching to asset catalogs and re-importing the pictures in. Look at this website:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog/StoringAppIconsandLaunchImagesinanAssetCatalog.html

hope that helps

Comment: thank you very much - it worked once, then I could not archive, then I redid it the very same way as the first time, but ow the icons are white again

Comment: Finally I figured it out - also thanks to AJHacker's comment. The png files were not created correctly with the correct settings!